# create a function that converts roman characters to integers

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function that reads any roman characters and convert it to integers in R.

I've tried this :

```
roman_to_integer <- function(roman) {
    convert = c("I"=1, "V"=5, "X"=10, "L"=50, "D"=500, "M"=1000)
    int = 0
    for (i in 1:length(roman)){
        value = convert[i]
        if (i+1 < nchar(roman) & convert[i+1] > value){
            int = int - value
        } else {
            int = int + value
        } 
        int
    }
}
```

How can i improve/fix this ?

Thank you !

Comment: You are not using standard R syntax. It looks like a strange R / Python / Javascript hybrid. The logical test for `if` statements must be surrounded by parentheses, and the conditional code should be wrapped in curly braces. There is no place for a semicolon operator here, and R has no increment operator like `int = +value`. Can I ask where you are learning R?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried to fix it and edited my question, regarding to your reponse. Am not there yet :)                                                                                                     Well, i am ltrying to learn by myself to program in Python and R.

Comment: There are several more issues. You need to wrap your code after `function()` in `{ }`. It doesn't make sense to return `print()` for an object, just return the object. You can't access a data frame's row names that easily,so it's best not to use them. `length()` returns the number of elements in a vector, but it seems that you want to return the number of characters in a string, so you'd want to use `nchar()` instead.

Comment: In short, there's a lot to fix here - if this is just an exercise to challenge yourself to learn R, I would suggest taking smaller bites at this.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help @Phil. I have edited my post regarding to your comments. Am still working on it. Yes, i'll do smaller bites :) Thanks ! But how can i create a dictionary in R instead of a data frame ?

Comment: There's really no valid reason to not use a data frame as a dictionary. The other alternative is a named vector (i.e. `c("V" = 5, ...)`) but it isn't any more convenient than using a data frame.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot ! I have edited my function. I don't get errors anymore but the function doesn't provide the output i want.

Answer (score 1):

```
v <- c("I", "V", "X", "L", "D", "M", "LXXIX")

as.integer(as.roman(v))

# [1]    1    5   10   50  500 1000   79
```

With `as.roman` you can do arithmetic operations as well like

```
as.roman("M") - as.roman("I")

# [1] CMXCIX
```

Comment: Yes, thank you I have seen this but i want to create that function.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that this is already implemented in base R?

```r
roman_number <- as.roman("XLII")
roman_number
#> [1] XLII

as.integer(roman_number)
#> [1] 42
```

You can look at the function implementation with `getAnywhere(".roman2numeric")`.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this function. But as i am still learning, i want to create a function that is more simple than the one implemented.